# Still Confused Between Event and Event Handlers in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Can someone please help me to understand what exactly is the "Event" and "Event handler" in following examples? According to [www.w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_events.asp) here is the list of some common events

[image]

so why some people still keep saying Click event handler? is Click **event** or **event handler**?

1.

```
$( "p" ).click(function() {
       alert("Which One is Event and which one Event Handler");
});
```

2. 

```
$("p").on("click",function(){
       alert("Which One is Event and which one Event Handler");
});
```

3. 

```
$("p").css("background-color","yellow");
```

Comment: The event is a click. The event handler (in your first two snippets) is the anonymous function.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, but how about the example 2 and 3?

Comment: There is neither an event nor an event handler in the third snippet

Comment: What does 3, `$("p").css("background-color","yellow");` have to do with anything? There are no events or event handlers there, only a simple method invocation which is completely unrelated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your code:

```
$("p").click(function() {
    // this function is the event handler of the "click" event
});
```

which is the same as:

```
$("p").on("click",function(){
   alert("Which One is Event and which one Event Handler");
});
```

[(see jQuery `on` documentation)](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

The following code, is not an event, just changes the style of the `p` elements:

```
$("p").css("background-color", "yellow");
```

Comment: Thanks Lante just one quick question, so what is on()?

Comment: its way that jQuery provided on 1.7 version to handle events. I added to my answer a link to jQuery documentation. On your code, it does the same as `.click(function () {`, but its a better practice to use `.on('click', function () { ... `

Answer (score 6):

The **event** is the action. The handler is the **receiver** of that action, usually a function.